Glance Text Rotation
Currently, I have a horizontal Widget; I would like to create a vertical one, which basically is the same one rotated 90 degrees. I'm checking the glance API, and I don't see any transformation method in the GlanceModifier. Do I have to use another type of property to make possible the rotation of a Text

In the end, Glance is a wrapper around RemoteViews. So, start by determining if text rotation is available for non-Glance app widgets. If it is, then how you do that may give you clues as to where to find a suitable modifier, or perhaps that modifier has not been written yet. If text rotation is not available for app widgets generally, you would need to handle that yourself, rendering the text to a bitmap, rotating the bitmap, and rendering the rotated bitmap via Glance.
